# Converting a string to a list: troubleshooting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm trying out the GC Content problem over at Rosalind. I figured I could read the contents of the provided FASTA format file into a list. Use the list to make a dictionary with the Rosalind ID as the key and the ATGC string as value. In order to do that I read the file into a string variable, remove the newlines, and split at the '>'. My problem is the list that is returned has an empty entry at index 0.

```
    with open('rosalind_gc.txt','r') as fileA:
        contents = fileA.read()
        contents = contents.replace('\n','')

        listA = contents.split('>')

        print(listA)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey there, can you please show me the input text sample and output text sample. And try to explain your problem more clearly. It's hard to understand. And welcome to stack! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your text file begins with ">" it's normal. For example :

```
'>test'.split(">")
```

will return :

```
['', 'test']
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the `constants` string start with `>`?

If it does, `constants.split(">", "")` will return `["", ...]` as there's a symbol at the start, which could explain why `listA[0]` returns `''`.

Based on your comment, it seems that this is the case, and if you wish to remove all the `''` items, then simply add `listA = [element for elements in contents if element]`.

Comment: typo, listA = [element for element in listA if e]

Comment: Tried that. It gives 'NameError: name 'listA' is not defined' as error.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to eliminate the empty strings you could use:

```
listA = [e for e in contents.split('>') if e]
```